# how to make vim looks for and display only files with .c or .h extension when displaying results of :find command

Tags: search, find

How can I make vim `:find` only files with `.c` or `.h` extensions?

For example, I am interested in finding `.c` files starting with `tsv` so I would run `:find tsv*`. This gives too many results; how do I make it specific to `.c`?

Comment: Doesn't `:find tsv*c` or `:find tsv*\.c` work?

Comment: it does but not sure how to look for .c and .h files together, ex: something like :find tsv*.{c,h}

Comment: Ah, then `:find tsv*[hc]` should do the trick.

Comment: It does, can you please add this as an answer I will accept

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:find` uses regexes as the regular search does. If you look at [`:h /[]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5b%5d) you'll see that using `[]` in a pattern allows to search for a collection:

```
\_[]
    A collection.  This is a sequence of characters enclosed in brackets.
    It matches any single character in the collection.
    Example     matches ~
    [xyz]       any 'x', 'y' or 'z'
    [a-zA-Z]$   any alphabetic character at the end of a line
```

So your pattern should be `:find tsv*[hc]`

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer

Comment: Its more glob than regex, no?

Comment: Good point Ben, that' probably more related to globbing